# For positive real numbers $a,b,c$ prove that:

Tags: inequality

For positive real numbers $a,b ,c$ prove that: $a^{b+c}b^{c+a}c^{a+b} ≤ (a^ab^bc^c)^2$

My working

$c^c≥b^c≥b^a$

$(c^c)^2 ≥ b^{a+c}$

Similarly
$(c^c)^2≥ a^{c+b} and (c^c)^2≥c^{a+b}$

Therefore
$(c^c)^6 ≥b^{a+c}c^{a+b}a^{c+b}$

But I do not know how to use it.

Comment: How did you get $(c^c)^6 ≥b^{a+c}c^{a+b}a^{c+b}$?

Comment: Perhaps you can use the rearrangement inequality

Comment: Solution on AoPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2323394p18574019

Comment: I assumed a≤b≤c

Answer (score 0):

Using W-GM-HM,
$$(a^a \cdot b^b \cdot c^c)^{\frac{1}{a+b+c}} \geq \frac{a+b+c}{\frac{a}{a}+\frac{b}{b}+\frac{c}{c}} = \frac{a+b+c}{3}$$
Using AM-GM,
$$\frac{a+b+c}{3} \geq \sqrt[3]{abc}$$
Combining these two, we get
$$a^a b^b c^c \geq (abc)^{\frac{a+b+c}{3}}$$
This gives
$$(a^a b^b c^c)^3 \geq (abc)^{a+b+c}$$
Divide by $(a^a b^b c^c)$ and get
$$a^{b+c}b^{c+a}c^{a+b} ≤ (a^ab^bc^c)^2$$

Comment: As an aside, that inequality isn't true, like for $ c = 1$, $ a = b = 2$. (Maybe OP required that $c$ was the maximum, so it's only true for $c$ but not for the other symmetric inequalities.)

Comment: @CalvinLin that was a nice point. But, now I placed an edit to make it a real proof. Check if it's okay.

Answer (score -1):

Isn't it simetric? If you got $(c^c)^6 \geq x$, you also can get $(a^a)^6 \geq x$ and $(b^b)^6 \geq x$, so it should be $ (a^ab^bc^c)^2 = ((a^a)^6(b^b)^6(c^c)^6)^{1/3} \geq x$. Check if this hold formaly.